# Automatic defining global variables in MATLAB

Tags: matrices, matlab

How could I define a set of variables automatically in MATLAB. For example: kt1 to kt_n*(2*n+1)

> `global kt1 kt2 kt3 kt4 kt5 kt6 kt7 kt8 kt9 kt10
>   n=2;
>   for i=1:n*(2*n+1)
>       eval(['kt',int2str(i),'=(i+i^2)/2'])
>   end`

I would like to global kt1:kt_n*(2*n+1) automatically, instead of first line.
I wonder if someone could help me. Thank you.

Comment: Will replacing kt1, ..., kt10 with a 1x10 array work for your application?

Comment: If you want to define global variables `kt1` ... `ktN` (for some $N$), here is what you could do :

    `for i=1:N
    eval(['global kt' num2str(i) ';']);
    end`

Comment: I'll make it an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to create global variables `kt1`, ..., `ktN` (for some $N$), here is what you could do :

```
for i=1:N
  eval(['global kt' num2str(i) ';']);
end
```